# What is the point of the CancellationToken in IHostedService.StartAsync in asp .net core?

Tags: c#, async-await, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm trying to implement a hosted service and I was wondering what I am expected to do with the CancellationToken in the `IHostedService.StartAsync` call.

There is quite a lot in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) about the cancellation token in `StopAsync` being essentially a timeout (5s by default) that means graceful shutdown is supposed to happen within a reasonable timeframe.

But regarding the token in `StartAsync`, there is not much information. If anything, the documentation specifies that the implementation shouldn't await on long running initialisation processes and should just return a long running task.
So if I support cancellation, should I pass the cancellation token to whatever creates that long running task? If yes, isn't cancelling this token a dumber version of `StopAsync`? Why would the framework ever do this?

And indeed, in Microsoft's own abstract [BackgroundService](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions/BackgroundService.cs), the implementation for `StartAsync`actually completely ignores that token and creates a new one which *will* be cancelled on call to `StopAsync`...

So am I to think that the whole point of that initial token passed by the framework is actually to be used in *blocking* 
initialisation processes nonetheless (despite the doc advising against it) by overriding the virtual `BackgroundService.StartAsync` method? e.g.

```
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // Block the thread for initialisation with cancellation (replace Task.Delay by actual initialisation)
        Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        // Start the long running task proper
        return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    protected override Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        // some long running process (write some actual background running code here)
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(_ => {while(!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested){}}, null, stoppingToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: It might not be due to specific usage of cancellation. The general rule is that each async method should have a cancellation token parameter. So that if the token is necessary in the future, it isn't a breaking change.

Answer (score 11):

The `CancellationToken` passed into the `StartAsync` can be used to determine if the start process should be canceled but as far as I understand, you already know that. This is written [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostedservice.startasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0).

> Indicates that the start process has been aborted.

If you look at [where `StartAsync` is called](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/release/3.0/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/Host.cs#L53), you can see that the `CancellationToken` which is passed into the `StartAsync` function is linked with [`IHostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime.applicationstopping?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0). As far as I understand, this token is just used if the shutdown of the application happens so early that not all hosted services have been fully started yet. However, I don't know if `StopAsync` will be called if the starting token is triggered (I'd have to dig further in the sources or search more in the docs).

To summarize:
The `CancellationToken` in the `StartAsync`-method should just be passed to any method called in `StartAsync` which supports cancellation. It will allow the app to shutdown gracefully in case the requested shutdown happens so early that the hosted service has not been fully started yet.

Comment: Hello @joelius , how about CancellationToken in StopAsync method , what is needed with that ? I am just confused with that ? I cannot find a place to consume it. Any advice will be appreciated.